# mongodb setFeatureCompatibilityVersion command not found

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-3.4

I'm trying to upgrade my mongodb from 3.2 to 3.4 and I try to set the compatibility version by:
`db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.2" } )`

But it says

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "no such command: 'setFeatureCompatibilityVersion', bad cmd: '{ setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"3.2\" }'",
        "code" : 59
}
```

I'm not sure why the command is not found. Can somebody point me out in whats wrong?

Here is the mongodb version info from `db.serverStatus().version`

> 3.2.20

P.S: I'm running the command on `admin` database and authenticated on it as a user with `root` role.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` shows it being new as of MongoDB 3.4, so it can't be run on a 3.2 server process:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/

The upgrade steps describe that running this command should be done after the server processes [have been upgraded to 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-replica-set/#enable-backwards-incompatible-newversion-features).